# Cannot read property 'of' of undefined for Observable after upgrading from Angular 2 to Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-services, rxjs5

The Following Service and its Observable was working fine up until I upgraded Angular 2 and RxJs to the latest versions.

The error says "***Cannot read property 'of' of undefined***" when trying to execute the following line of code:

```
   if (this.loggedContact) {
            return Observable.of(this.loggedContact);
        }
```

I see that the this.loggedContact already has value. Looks like it considers Observable as undefined. Has something changed the way we used to return an object as an Observable?

```
 "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "angular2-busy": "2.0.4",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "core-js": "2.5.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "ng2-completer": "^1.3.1",
    "ng2-toasty": "^4.0.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.3",
    "systemjs": "^0.20.18",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.17"
```

Following is the service:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


loggedContact: CostarContactVM;
observable: Observable<any>;

getLoggedContact(): Observable<Contact> {
        if (this.loggedContact) {
            return Observable.of(this.loggedContact);
        }
        else if (this.observable)
            return this.observable;
        else {
            this.observable = this.http.get(this.contactUrl)
                .map(res => {
                    this.observable = null;
                    if (res.status == 400) {
                        return "FAILURE";
                    }
                    else if (res.status === 200) {
                        this.loggedContact = res.json() as Contact;
                        return this.loggedContact;
                    }
                })
                .share();
            return this.observable; 
        }
    }
```

Following is the System.Config for the same:

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        meta: {
            '*': { authorization: true }
        },
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        map: {
            app: 'app',
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs'
            },
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

Comment: I may sound stupid with this but can you try this `import 'rxjs/Rx'; ` remove all the other imports

Comment: I am sorry but this did not help

Comment: I'd suggest to provide a way to replicate the problem then - a plunk, a repo, etc, since posted code doesn't reflect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the issue with my upgrade to Angular 4.0. Basically, I upgraded my RxJs from 5.0.1 to 5.4.3 and it now supports HttpClient module from location @angular/common/http rather than Http from @angular/http.

I upgraded all refrences to HttpClient and updated my code like the following and it fixed the issue. I hope it helps someone. 
The point is during upgade to Angular 4, remember to upgrade your http to httpClient.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ContactService {


loggedContact: CostarContactVM;

  getLoggedContact(): Observable<ContactVM> {
     return this.httpClient.get<ContactVM>(this.contactUrl)
        .catch(this.handleError)
        .do((data) => {
            this.assignPermissions(data);
        });
}
```